# Conflicting javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bunch of jquery/javascript running on a new site I'm building, and of course I've run into a conflict. I can't figure out where it's coming from as I'm not that great with js. There is a sticky relocate function that's supposed to show a navigation bar when you start scrolling the page but since I've added in a category filter function, the navigation bar no longer shows.

Site: [audreylynn](http://www.audreylynn.net/demo)

Comment: jquery conflicting with javascript... thats not possible... try using some debugger like firebug for firefox or if you are using chrome use the developer tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks your javascript has an error which is probably causing your problem.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null   /demo/:75
```

Looking at the code:

```
70  // Ensure target exists
71  var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
72  if (target) {
73      
74      // Find location of target
75      var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 95;
76      $(this).click(function(event) {
```

It looks like your check on line 72 should be:

```
if ($target.length > 0) {
```

To ensure that the element actually exists. (Because "#tellShow-anchor" doesn't)

Comment: in line 71, shouldn't that , be a ; ?

Comment: I'm an idiot :o) Thank you so much for the incredibly fast help.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and mark the answer as accepted so the question doesn't show up as unanswered.